# Getting "Server returned HTTP response code: 400" while connecting to FCM from Server app

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to access FCM from my server app. Checked the example provided into [here](https://www.zoftino.com/android-notification-data-messages-from-app-server-using-firebase-cloud-messaging)! But getting error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/unsaarmdm/messages:send
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at asd.MessagesClientFCMServer.sendMessageToFcm(MessagesClientFCMServer.java:66)
    at asd.MessagesClientFCMServer.sendData(MessagesClientFCMServer.java:40)
    at asd.MessagesClientFCMServer.main(MessagesClientFCMServer.java:37)
```

I've already created the firebase project called "unsaarmdm" and downloaded the json file that contains the private key. Also added the Google API Client library into my project.

Below is the code snippets:

```
    private static String FCM_DEALS_ENDPOINT 
    = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/unsaarmdm/messages:send";
    //https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/unsaarmdm/messages:send

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MessagesClientFCMServer fcmClient = new MessagesClientFCMServer();
        fcmClient.sendData();
    }
    private void sendData(){
        sendMessageToFcm(getFcmMessageJSONData());
    }


    //Using HttpURLConnection it send http post request containing data to FCM server
    private void sendMessageToFcm(String postData) {
        try {

            HttpURLConnection httpConn = getConnection();

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream()); 
            wr.writeBytes(postData);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            log.info(response.toString());          

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
                .fromStream(new FileInputStream("C:/dev/Firebase_private_key/unsaarmdm-firebase-adminsdk.json"))
                .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPE));
        googleCredential.refreshToken();
        String token = googleCredential.getAccessToken();
        return token;
    }

    //create HttpURLConnection setting Authorization token
    //and Content-Type header
    private HttpURLConnection getConnection() throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(FCM_DEALS_ENDPOINT);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessToken());
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.connect();
        return httpURLConnection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The url looks more like `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

This is a weird part, I'm aware the docs say to use the URL you are using, but I have a working implementation (and I know I spent some time debbuging this) with the URL i just mentioned, try and let me know :) we all can learn.

Make sure you include the server key into the `Authorization` header (which it seems you are doing ok).